# removing white background in UIImageView

Tags: uiimageview

in my app there is an option to add image. when i'm adding an image and even if i don't add any image, there is always a white background. how can i get rid of it? (all my images are transparent (png))
Thanks.

Comment: make it more clear.. its not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

set the view's background color to clear color on which you are adding the image.
for example:

`imgView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];`